# SonarQube API: Retrieving a list of users assigned to a project permission?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'm trying to find a list of users for a specific project (by projectKey) who possess the issueadmin permission. I've found a documented API that gets me pretty close:

```
api/permissions/search_project_permissions
```

but the response that I get back only has summary information: counts of groups/users for each permission type.

[search_project_permissions response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPLYX.png)

Does anybody know if there's a way to get to the login details for the users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an "internal" web service (meaning **it could change without notice!**) that does this. You'll use it like so:

```
http://myserver.myco.com/api/permissions/users?projectId=[project guid]&permission=issueadmin
```

In Web API interface use the "Show Internal API" checkbox at the top of the left column to see it.

Answer (score 3):

just noticed in Sonarqube v6.7 it works as follows:

```
https://<SQserver>/api/permissions/users?projectKey=<KEY>
https://<SQserver>/api/permissions/users?projectKey=<KEY>&permission=issueadmin
https://<SQserver>/api/permissions/users?projectKey=<KEY>&permission=issueadmin&permission=scan
```

All possible permissions are (reg. Browse, See Source Code, Administer Issues, Administer and Execute Analysis):

- admin
- codeviewer
- issueadmin
- scan
- user

Comment: Nice one. This isn't working if you do not already have admin perms though. I get "Insufficient privileges". I'm a regular user trying to find the admin for a project using this trick

Comment: It seems the endpoint became internal service , but per current docs, it should be sufficient to have project admin https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/permissions/users?internal=true

Answer (score 0):

Those looking for UI to API Mapping:

```
[UI]Browse                       ==  [API]user
[UI]See Source Code              ==  [API]codeviewer
[UI]Administer Issues            ==  [API]issueadmin
[UI]Administer Security Hotspots ==  [API]securityhotspotadmin
[UI]Administer                   ==  [API]admin
[UI]Execute Analysis             ==  [API]scan
```